# Printf-like function with optional format string argument and GCC format type-checking

Tags: c, gcc, printf

I have created a `printf`-like function which takes the following arguments:

- One mandatory argument (custom error code)
- **Optional format string**
- Variable count of format arguments

The function prototype looks like:

```
int my_printf(int err_code, ...);
```

`err_code` also includes information whether the format string (and possible format tags) are given.

If they are given, I can extract the format string using the `va_arg` function and pass it to `vfprintf` together with the rest of the arguments.

The calls look like:

```
my_printf(-ERR_SIMPLE);
my_printf(-ERR_COMPLICATED, "Error: problem with %d", 123);
```

Unfortunately, I am unable to use the GCC attribute for format type-checking since it needs a `string-index`:

> format (archetype, string-index, first-to-check)

Is it still possible to do the type-checking anyhow?
Solutions using helper macros, helper functions, modifying the optional format string part etc are acceptable.

**Update:**
I am unsure whether passing a modified `va_list` to `vfprintf`-like functions is OK. See comments.
If possible, it would be better to avoid this and use macros or something else for the optional format string part.

Comment: How does your function even work at all? How do you strip the format string argument out of the valist?

Comment: @KerrekSB I get the format string with const char *fmt = va_arg(args, const char *);. Then I can simply call vfprintf(stdout, fmt, args);

Comment: Isn't that UB? I'm pretty sure you can't pass a valist to a function if you've already started monkeying with it...

Comment: @KerrekSB I am not sure. It seems to work with GCC 4.4.5 on x86. I guess I should avoid that. The question is still valid (and updated), however.

Comment: Well, if we're already in the territory or terrible hacks, I wouldn't worry too much about getting the attributes right :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB I want to avoid the hacks as much as possible (if they are hacks actually) since it should work with different GCC versions on different architectures. Basically, it is all fighting against the need of the 6 extra characters (`my_printf(-ERR_CODE, NULL)`)...

Comment: Regarding your update: Yes, you can (and must) pass a valist to `vprintf`, but you mustn't manipulate the list before passing it (or reuse it after passing it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Sorry, I hadn't seen that you *had* tried with `__attribute__`. My bad).

You might try experimenting with "argument counting" as described here:

http://locklessinc.com/articles/overloading/

I don't know if this can result in GCC selectively applying argument checking though; but I think it should.

**UPDATE** it appears to be working, with an added `#define` hack:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int printf_1(int err)
{
        printf("Got error %d\n", err);
        return 0;
}

int printf_2(int error, char *string)
{
        printf("Error %d and message %s\n", error, string);
        return 0;
}

int printf_3(int error, char *fmt, ...) __attribute__ ((format (printf, 2, 3)));

int printf_3(int error, char *fmt, ...)
{
        printf("Received full string err=%d, fmt=%s\n", error, fmt);
        return 0;
}

#define printf_4        printf_3
#define printf_5        printf_3
#define printf_6        printf_3
#define printf_7        printf_3
#define printf_8        printf_3
#define printf_9        printf_3
#define printf_10       printf_3


#define COUNT_PARMS2(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, _, ...) _
#define COUNT_PARMS(...)\
        COUNT_PARMS2(__VA_ARGS__, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)

#define CAT(A, B) CAT2(A, B)
#define CAT2(A, B) A ## B

#define myprintf(...)\
        CAT(printf_, COUNT_PARMS(__VA_ARGS__))(__VA_ARGS__)

int main()
{
        myprintf(19);
        myprintf(19, "Hello");
        myprintf(19, "Hello '%s'", "world");
        // Warning!
        myprintf(19, "Hello '%s'", "world", 42);
        myprintf(19, 42);
        return 0;
}
```

I correctly receive (gcc 4.6.2):

```
$ gcc -W -Wall -o test test.c

test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:48:2: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
test.c:49:2: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘printf_2’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
test.c:9:5: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
```